# What is the most memory-effective way of storing binary matrix in c#?

Tags: c#

How to store 2-dimensional arrayof logical values in c#, so that it takes least space?

Comment: Depends of its properties. Is it sparse? What is the value range? Cardinality?

Comment: Value range is from true to false - or from 0 to 1, if you prefer. Cardinality is varied, but in the hundreds. While it is not sparse, it does consist of varying sequences of 1 and 0, with less then 10  changes between them in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) uses one bit per logical value. The most efficient would be to implement your own two-dimensional BitArray. Use .NET reflector to get the BitArray source code.

Comment: Thank you! I think, that for a time, i could manage with storing the whoole matrix in 1-dimentional array. Maybe with some extension like "getItem(x,y)" or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 32 columns you can use a 32 bit integer and use bit wise operations to turn on an off bits.

I do this in C all the time, should work in c# aswell

Comment: I was thinking about using char array with 8 bitmasks, with th retrieving being something a[index] = b[index/8] & masks[index%8] > 0